# IE7 z-index relative bug with three levels of relative elements

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

Here's the HTML:

CSS

```
/* Position and z-index */
.level2 {
    position: relative;
}
.level3 {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
.level4 {
    position: absolute;
}

/* Styling */
.level2 {
    width: 200px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    background: lightgreen;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: right;
}
.level3 {
    width: 200px;
    background: lightblue;
    text-align: right;
}
.level4 {
    background: lightyellow;
    top: 5px;
    left: 5px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 300px;
    text-align: right;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="level2">
    <div class="level3">
        <div class="level4">level4</div>
        level3
    </div>
    level2
</div>
<div class="level2">
    level2
</div>
<div class="level2">
    level2
</div>
```

In Chrome, `.level4` is over `.level2`, but not in IE7. How can I get `.level4` to cover `.level2` in IE7?

Comment: Doesn't giving level4 a z-index work? It should cover as it is

Comment: @Huangism, no, it doesn't.  I tried adding 1 and 2.

Comment: I cannot test this as I don't have IE7. Your client should really stop using older IEs

Answer (score 0):

"In Internet Explorer positioned elements generate a new stacking context, starting with a z-index value of 0. Therefore z-index doesn’t work correctly"

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="level2">
        <div class="level3">
            <div class="level4">level4</div>
            level3
        </div>
        level2
    </div>
    <div class="level2">
        level2
    </div>
    <div class="level2">
        level2
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

Conditional comment Only for IE 7

```
<!--[if IE 7]>
    <style>
        .wrapper > div:first-child{
            z-index: 2;
        }
    </style>
<![endif]-->
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KkcMB/show/)

**[Click Here](http://www.brenelz.com/blog/squish-the-internet-explorer-z-index-bug/)** for Useful article

Hope it Helps.